# Not sure why my Makefile target is not working

Tags: bash, makefile, build, gnu-make

I have:

```
CURL=curl -L

all: \
    cach1/nix-2.0.4-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2

cach1/nix-2.0.4-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2: | cach1
    ${CURL} 'https://nixos.org/releases/nix/nix-2.0.4/nix-2.0.4-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2' > $@

cach1:
    mkdir -p cach1
```

I get

```
$ rm -rf cach1
$ make  -f Makefile
mkdir -p cach1
$ ls -l cach1/
```

Why so ??

Answer (score 0):

I had a space preceding the target recipe instead of a TAB.